# How can I create a bootable Ubuntu USB?

Tags: live-usb, startup-disk-creator

I have updated to Ubuntu 17.10. Now I want to create a bootable USB stick to use on other machines or to install 17.10 on a new machine. Start up Disk Creator recognizes my USB Drive, but is looking for a CD/DVD containing a source file.  I assume an ISO file.  I cannot change the source location and even if could, I have no idea where to find the 17.10 ISO on my hard drive.

I found sample code to create the USB using the terminal but I can not get that to work either, I keep getting a message saying the add command can not be found!

Must I be signed into the root directory to use the necessary  commands and if so how do I do that?

Comment: You can see in the screenshot in the accepted answer that the **Other** button in Startup disk Creator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCx2h.png is highlighted because it has been clicked.

Answer (score 3):

You must download the ISO file from https://www.ubuntu.com/download and then select the downloaded ISO in **StartupDiskCreator**.

Comment: Thanks Cialu,   Did all   all you suggested,  but the created USB will not boot and is READ ONLY.

Comment: Did you select in the computer BIOS the USB boot option?

Answer (score -1):

The 1st: Format your USB FAT format.
The 2nd: Download & install Unetbootin; Then it has UI for burning USB boot-able Ubuntu from ISO file.

https://unetbootin.github.io/

Comment: I have upgraded to 17.10.  Do I not have an the ISO file somewhere on my hard drive?

Comment: Ducvd,   Thanks but Unetbootin is to criptic for a Newbe like me

Comment: Yes Computer is set to boot from the USB drive.  but thanks for asking